# Importing pandas doesn't work properly when launching script with double click

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I have a script with different methods and classes.
When I run it in Spyder, it runs well and I can do all the stuffs I have to do.

The problem arises when I want to just double click on the program's name `my_program.py`, if I do that, the script doesn't run.

I have just troubleshot it and I have realized that, if I don't import the pandas library, I can run the script by double clicking on it in the folder.
(The program is a GUI so, I can notice that the windows opens properly)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please go through this and update your question

Comment: As mentioned above by Nikhil, update your question, but I have an idea why it does not work for you. I think you are using Spyder provided my anaconda, which has pandas built-in, but you haven't installed it on your system. Anaconda creates its own environment, install pandas from your command prompt or Powershell by using `pip install pandas`

Comment: Hi, sorry its my first question here. I tried what you mentioned, but, i have already installed pandas, so i guess this is not the problem. I tried to build a Batch file which call `my_prgram.py` but imposible to fix the problem

Comment: Please provide the code in my_program.py

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed? I made the mistake multiple times that my import didnt work and I was on a different version by accident.